# How to modify specifically the very first index[0] of response value before it gets passed to another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, httpresponse

I currently have this ajax request which runs a function which embeds Tableau Views. Then, I insert security token in order for users to access Tableau Reports without them having to log into **Tableau** again when they are on this site.

My process is,I inject the security token when I receive responses from the database then I look for a keyword 'ticket' to add the security token to it. It works perfectly up until if the `response[0]` is not containing the keyword 'ticket', meaning I will need to add that keyword to the `response[0]` before it gets passed to the next function.

Here is my attempt: `response[0].TReports[0].url.replace('server/views','server/trusted/ticket/views');`

but when the next function runs, the response is not the one that has been modified. How to receive the modified 'response[0]'?

```js
  $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
          url: _config.GetHeadersByClientAPI,
          dataType: 'json',
         contentType: 'application/json',
          data: JSON.stringify(data),
          success: function (response) {
          var vizArray = [];
          var items = '';
response[0].TReports[0].url.replace('server/views','server/trusted/ticket/views');   //This is my attempt to edit the value, however it is modifying what it is //being passed to the next forEach. 
         
                        response.forEach(function (data) {
                            vizArray[data] = data;
          var trustedticket=ticket;
                            var header = vizArray[data].THeaderTitle;
                            var header_id = vizArray[data].THeaderTitle.replace(" ", "");
                            var reports = vizArray[data].TReports;
          
                            $('#report-group-title').append("<a href='#" + header_id + "' class='list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed' data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#sidebar' aria-expanded='false'><i id='h' class='fa fa-book'></i> <span class='d-none d-md-inline'>" + header + " </span></a>   <div class='collapse' id='" + header_id + "'></div >");
                            items += "<a href='#" + header_id + "' class='list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed' data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#sidebar' aria-expanded='false'><i id='h' class='fa fa-book'></i> <span class='d-none d-md-inline'>" + header + " </span></a>   <div class='collapse' id='" + header_id + "'></div >";
                            var list = '';
                            $.each(reports, function load(j) {
                                vizArray[j] = reports[j]
                                var name = vizArray[j].name;
                                var url = vizArray[j].url.replace("ticket",trustedticket); //Here I inject my security //token
           
                                var hash = vizArray[j].hash;
                                var vizOptions = {
                                    showTabs: true,
                                    hideToolbar: true
                                };
           
                                var vizDiv = document.createElement('div');
                                vizDiv.id = hash + 'Viz';
                                document.getElementById('vizes').appendChild(vizDiv);
                                reports.viz = new tableauSoftware.Viz(
                                    document.getElementById(hash + 'Viz'),
                                    url,
                                    vizOptions
                                )
                                console.log(name);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String.replace is non-mutating.

Consider the following code:

```
var a = "foobar";
a.replace("foo", "bar");
console.log(a); // "foobar"
```

It is easy to see that `replace` is not mutating a, instead returning the manipulated string containing "barbar" which is what you'd expect had the replace function mutated a.

Instead, you could do something like:

```
a = a.replace("foo", "bar");
```

Which would assign the mutated value to a.

In your case:

```
response[0].TReports[0].url = response[0].TReports[0].url.replace('server/views','server/trusted/ticket/views');
```